# nginx redirect now working, please advice

Tags: nginx

After adding letsencrypt Im trying to get a proper redirects
http://example.com and https://example.com to https://www.example.com

https//example.com to https://www.example.com is not working..

also do I need separate tags for www and non www? or would server_name example.com www.example.com work?

should I be generating letsencrypt certificate for mydomain.com?

Please advice and thank you in advance.

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/example.com/public_html;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pe$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all get rid of this totally. It's a horrible piece of Nginx config and I have no idea why the good folk of Certbot include it.

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

You can change your top server block to catch all non https connections and redirect them, like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

However, that will catch all requests on port 80, even if someone just puts in your server IP. If you don't want that and only want to catch traffic for your domain then you need two server blocks, one for your domain and one for everthing else, like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Thats all your http traffic dealt with. There are a couple of ways to do your SSL redirects, you will need either a combined certificate with both www and non www domains on, or a certificate each. If you get a combined one then the order you list the domains can be important. As you intend to use www then list that as the first domain.

Then add another server block at the bottom to catch non the non www domain and redirect, like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate ....
    ssl_certificate_key ....
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for taking the time to help me. I got it solved.